# Makefile for calling make with multiple targets

Tags: makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I have a rule in a makefile which uses [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to convert wav files to another format.

Makefile:

```
INPUTFILE?=file1.wav
OUTFILE=$(INPUTFILE:.wav=.s32)

wav_to_s32:
    @sox $(INPUTFILE) -r 16000 $(OUTFILE)
```

How would I make this work for multiple files specified at input (with multiple outputs)?

```
INPUTFILE?=file1.wav file2.wav file3.wav
```

Comment: To be clear there's nothing about this particular to Cygwin. The answers below are true of most make implementations on any platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52985622/8012646), the key here is pattern rules. If you want to automate all conversions for all files that you list in your `INPUTFILE` variable you can complete your initial version and that other answer like this:

```
INPUTFILE?=file1.wav file2.wav file3.wav
OUTFILE=$(INPUTFILE:.wav=.s32)

.PHONY: wav_to_s32
wav_to_s32: $(OUTFILE)

%.s32: %.wav
    sox $< -r 16000 $@
```

This tells make that:

1. `wav_to_s32` is not a real file, it's just a short name for something else (it is a "*phony*" target).
2. When invoked with `make wav_to_s32` it shall build all files listed in `$(OUTFILE)`.

And if you prefer make to discover automatically the input files, you can further improve all this with:

```
INPUTFILE := $(wildcard *.wav)
OUTFILE   := $(patsubst %.wav,%.s32,$(INPUTFILE))

.PHONY: wav_to_s32
wav_to_s32: $(OUTFILE)

%.s32: %.wav
    sox $< -r 16000 $@
```

Note that make is smart enough to not reconvert a file if it has been converted already and did not change since. It is even the main purpose of make: track inter-files dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the following [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) in your makefile:

```
%.s32: %.wav
    sox $< -r 16000 $@
```

The rule above will build `.s32` files from `.wav` files.

With that rule in your makefile you could call `make` for multiple targets in the following way:

```
 $ make foo.s32 bar.s32
 sox foo.wav -r 16000 foo.s32
 sox bar.wav -r 16000 bar.s32
```

It generates `foo.s32` and `bar.s32` from `foo.wav` and `bar.wav`, respectively.